# RecyclerView inside a viewpager without fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I'm trying to implement something like a view pager wizard (two steps in a activity), in which I'm trying to implement a recycler view inside of a view pager. The first view/layout in the pager would consist of a recycler view, in which the user would be allowed to select an area from a list, on selecting the area the pager would call the second view/layout for the user to enter additional information.

Now, no matter what I do, recycler view won't show up inside the view pager. I think I've messed up my layouts. Any help? Thanks

AreaActivity

```
 public class AreaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private TechAreaAdapter tAdapter;
    private List<TechAreas> _techAreaList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tech_areas);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPagerVertical);

        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        _techAreaList = new ArrayList<>();
        tAdapter = new TechAreaAdapter(this, _techAreaList);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(3, dpToPx(10), true));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(tAdapter);

        // row click listener
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                TechAreas techAreas = _techAreaList.get(position);
                //onclick move to the next view in the pager - viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));

        getTechAreaList();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            //Test
        }
    }

        private void getTechAreaList() {

        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<List<TechAreas>> call = apiService.getTechAreaList();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<TechAreas>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<TechAreas>> call, Response<List<TechAreas>> response) {
                _techAreaList.clear();
                _techAreaList.addAll(response.body());
                tAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<TechAreas>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch json: " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * RecyclerView item decoration - give equal margin around grid item
     */
    public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

        private int spanCount;
        private int spacing;
        private boolean includeEdge;

        public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
            this.spanCount = spanCount;
            this.spacing = spacing;
            this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
        }

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
            int column = position % spanCount; // item column

            if (includeEdge) {
                outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

                if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                    outRect.top = spacing;
                }
                outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
            } else {
                outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
                if (position >= spanCount) {
                    outRect.top = spacing; // item top
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Converting dp to pixel
     */
    private int dpToPx(int dp) {
        Resources r = getResources();
        return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
    }


    class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((View) object);
        }

        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

            int resId = 0;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    resId = R.id.layout_choose_area;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    resId = R.id.layout_add_info;
                    break;
            }
            return findViewById(resId);
        }
    }}
```

Main Layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:mContext="AreaActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_tech_areas" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Content Layout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_tech_areas">

    <CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerVertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_choose_area"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_add_info"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView/>

         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_interest"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="@string/lbl_enter_interest"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </CustomViewPager>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Custom View Pager

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }}
```

Comment: where are the `fragments` ? for `viewPager`

Comment: I want to do this without fragments.

Comment: @Ani, viewPager is made to be used with Fragments. It's possible without but not recommended. Is there a specific reason for not using them?

Comment: @Ani you want to do it without `fragments`, great why? well i said about fragments because you have different views in different fragments , giving you more control over those views , the way you are doing you are not inflating any views

Comment: @Mental That's not true at all. It might be more common these days to use `ViewPager` with `Fragment`s, but it was not made specifically to be used with them.

Comment: @MikeM. explained it very clearly ,thumbs up

Comment: Oh, whoops. Please ignore my original comment. Sorry about that. I didn't notice you had already added the `View`s directly to the `ViewPager` in its layout file. Are you sure you're seeing your content layout? That is, `<CustomViewPager>` should have the fully qualified class name in the tag. Otherwise, it'll throw an Exception. Also, if nothing else is going inside the `<ConstraintLayout>`, you should remove it, and just add the `<RecyclerView>` directly.

Comment: @MikeM. yes, I have given the full name, I purposely edited it out while posting. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, I just dropped your code into an empty project, with a simple list `RecyclerView.Adapter`, and it shows up for me. Are you sure you're not seeing the `RecyclerView`? Is it possibly just empty? That is, might the problem be in the `Adapter`, or maybe `getTechAreaList()`? Have you debugged there to be sure that you're ending up with a non-empty list? What happens if you set a color as the `RecyclerView`'s `background`?